# ZF 2 - Best way to bind some attributes of an object with a form?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an object `User` and I provide a form to edit some attribute like username, mail etc but not all **attributes**.

`User` implements `ArraySerializable`.

To populate my form, I'm using `bind` method to bind fields value with my object. But after validation, my binded object (User) have other attributes null.

**How could I precise that I want only populate values of from ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you manually hydrate the object (extract) and then setData on the form:

```
$array = $userHydrator->extract($userModel);
$form->setData($array);
```

Then you don't need to bind the object, and the object won't be affected by the form.

Comment: Yes It's what I'm doing now, but I was thinking to do that with `bind` method and `setValidationGroup` like @Crisp said .. Never mind, I'll continue with your method. Thank you all.

Comment: In fact, with your method, I should use `set*` in my object because if I populate my objet from data form, `exchangeArray($data)` will produce the same problem, I mean, populate `null` values ... So, I must use setter ?

Comment: but you said you never wanted to populate your object at all or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I want populate only 2 attributes of my object, from 2 fields. And I want to keep values of others attributes.

Comment: this should work then depending on your exchange array method, which if sensible will only effect the fields passed by the form (the two fields).
You could always use your hydrator with the form data on your object to set the two fields. it should work fine..

Comment: Ok, I understand ! Actually my `exchangeArray` method work like this : `$this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;`. So, It will be better if It works like this : `if($data['id'] != null){ $this->id = $data['id']`  ... ?

Comment: I would do this:
foreach item in the array, if it's valid for this object, update the attribute, possibly whitelisting the acceptable attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the forms `setValidationGroup()` method to only validate those values

```
 $form->setValidationGroup(array('username', 'email'));
```

Comment: I'm doing this but it binds all values and not only validate values ... Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Really? I've never come across that behaviour, other values usually remain untouched in my experience. What you could do is `setBindOnValidate(Form::BIND_MANUAL)` and then use your objects' `set*()` methods to set only the data you're interested in changing

Comment: Yes, it's what i'm doing now but I was thinking about a best way (like `setValidationGroup`) with the `bind` method...

Comment: Right, gotcha. You could render the other form values as hidden inputs in the form, that way they'll be populated with existing values on POST